# To check MyBat.bat file is running or not in C#

Tags: c#, batch-file, cmd

How can I check through C# code, if MyBat.bat file is running or not in the system.

I have tried this but not working properly.Please suggest some other way.

```
Process proc = new Process();
proc.StartInfo.FileName = @"D:\MyBat.bat";
if (proc.Start())
{
     Console.Write("This is bat files Open!.");
}
else
{
    Console.Write("Welcome");
}
```

I only want to check MyBat.bat file is running in the system or not. Because .bat file run in Command Prompt so how can i verify that MyBat.bat file is running.

Comment: have you tried this `proc.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;`

Comment: "not working properly" isn't a proper description of what's happening. Surely you can provide more info that that?

Comment: You want to see if someone is running `MyBat.bat` on your computer? That's kind of impossible, because as you've correctly said, it's just a script for Command Prompt. In any case, your code is starting a *new* process, not getting information about existing processes.

Comment: You can never get this 100% accurate.  The command processor might be substituted, the .bat file might be referred to by a symbolic link, there is an inevitable threading race.  Look for an observable side-effect instead, whatever you *really* care about to want to write code like this.

Answer (score 3):

You should invoke your batch file via `cmd.exe /c`, not directly.

so:

```
var command = "foo.bat";
Process p = new Process(){
    StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", "/c " + command)
};
var started = p.Start();

if(started)
{
    Console.WriteLine("started");
    var sync = true; //or false, see below
    if(sync)
    {
        //either wait synchronously
        p.WaitForExit();
        Console.WriteLine("finished");
    }
    else
    {
        //or wait for an exit event asynchronously
        p.Exited += (a, b) => { Console.WriteLine("finished"); }
    }


}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("not started");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know right now, you can check the HasExited property.

> var isRunning = !myProcess.HasExited;

If it's a quick process, just wait for it.

> myProcess.WaitForExit();

If you're starting one up in the background, subscribe to the Exited event after setting EnableRaisingEvents to true.

> myProcess.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
>
> myProcess.Exited += (sender, e) => {  MessageBox.Show("Process exited"); };